# Unable to create an EXE file from Ruby script

Tags: ruby, ocra

I am unable to create an EXE file from Ruby script.

```
require 'socket'

class Server
  def initialize(ip, port)
    @server = TCPServer.open(ip, port)
    @clients = Array.new
    run
  end

  def run
    loop {
      Thread.start(@server.accept) do |client|
        @clients << client
        client.puts 'Connection established'
        listen_user_messages(client)
      end
    }.join
  end

  def listen_user_messages(client)
    loop {
      msg = client.gets.chomp
      @clients.each do |other_client|
        if other_client != client
          other_client.puts "#{msg}"
        end
      end
    }
  end
end

Server.new('localhost', 19937)
```

I'm trying to run the following command:

> ocra server.rb

but it freezes on the message

> === Loading script to check dependencies

I've also tried to use exerb:

> ruby exerb server.rb

It builds an exe file, but I am unable to use it:

> server.rb:1:in `require': No such file to load -- socket (LoadError)
>           from server.rb:1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'socket'
require 'rubygems'
exit if Object.const_defined?(:Ocra) #allow ocra to create an exe without executing the entire script
```

Add the above to your script, this should allow it to generate.
Ocra cannot see ruby gems and other files at times if you don't include 'rubygems'